# Getting a file via an API with the file name containing a plus sign

Tags: http, url, download

We are currently working with an API for file upload and download.

We upload the file successfully, yet we can't download it. We have found that some of the files contain a '+' character which seems to be the issue here.

My question is, if we call the API like so :

```
nameoffile = "testing+test"
https://sitename/api/filesystem/nameoffile
```

Could there be another way of calling the API so the clients/browsers handle the name in the way we need them to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You're talking about **URLEncoding** special characters: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm

In your case, a '+' character encodes to "%2B":

```
nameOfFile = "testing%2Btest"
url = "https://www.google.com/abc/"+nameOfFile
```

Comment: cool, will this revert back to the + character when viewing the file ? So on the server it will be read back as "testing+test" file name ?

Comment: I can't say that without knowing what server you're using, but all the major web containers provide for URLEncoding/Decoding (Apache, Tomcat, Jetty, Netty, etc)

Comment: using IIS on a windows Server 2012r2